# How can i add a tabbarcontroller into a navigation application

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I have a navigation application with 3 views, in my second view, I want add a `tarbarcontroller` and control another two views, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a **tabBarController** include two tabs:**controller1** & **controller1**, push it whenever you want.

```
UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController * controller1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController * controller2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1, controller2 nil];
[controller1 release];
[controller2 release];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
[tabBarController release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a new Tab controller and attach it as a subview to your nav controller in that view.